# Is Apotheosis cosmetic or functional?

Tags: cleric, dungeon-world

Apotheosis states that the cleric permanently gains a physical characteristic of his deity. Examples given are claws, wings made of sapphires, and an all seeing third eye.

Assuming functionality as described, an all seeing eye is extremely powerful and claws relatively mundane.  Assuming cosmetic, I would have just written "third eye" instead of "all seeing."

My assumption is that you work out some reasonable functionality with the player, i.e. claws would be fine, but wings made of sapphires may be too heavy to fly high, and your special eye would only open on occasion and give mysterious visions.

However, I am curious if it is more explicitly stated elsewhere, or if not, what has your experience with this move been like?

I love this move and want to make sure I do it right.  Still reading the rules, but my PCs-to-be all share my curiosity and we wanted to take it to the internet.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

PS We are talking of having a Pastafarian cleric whose Aposteosis would grant a noodly appendage in place of his nose, and whenever he prays for guidance I would point the way or tap him lightly with a foam pool noodle.

Comment: Just a note that an all seeing eye might not be that convenient at all: Does it *always* see all? Guess you are going to have trouble sleeping or concentrating sometimes! Isn't seeing *everything* a bit of an information overload? Guess you are going to roll Discern Realities if you want to exactly see what the wizard is doing in his tower!

Comment: I love the noodly appendage idea for a Pastafarian cleric. Could that appendage change what he can use and carry in his hands, or enhance his Defy Danger in some ways?

Answer (score 10):

A cosmetic change is a fictional, descriptive change which, in Dungeon World, means it should have a functional, prescriptive change in the game. The game suggests figuring out the new ability as a group.

> ### Playing the Game: Character Change
>
> Advancement, like everything else in Dungeon World, is both prescriptive and descriptive. Prescriptive means that when a player changes their character sheet the character changes in the fiction. Descriptive means that when the character changes in the fiction the player should change the character sheet to match.
>   This isn’t a benefit or detriment to the players or the GM; it’s not an excuse to gain more powers or take them away. It’s just a reflection of life in Dungeon World.
>
> Descriptive changes only happen when the character has clearly gained access to an ability. It’s not up to any one player to decide this—if you think a character qualifies for a new ability, discuss it as a group.

Given that it's a magically gifted boon from a deity, I could imagine an all-seeing eye providing different, previously unavailable results from Discern Realities. Likewise, the weight of sapphire wings wouldn't necessarily prohibit flying. It's all up to the group.